# Generate all possible combinations of array columns in python

Tags: python, combinations, cartesian-product

For example, I have array like this

```
[
  [1,2,3],
  [4],
  [5,6],
]
```

I want to generate all combinations from the list above, which if it should look something like this.

```
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 6]
[2, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 6]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from the built-in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html) library

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6]))
[(1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6)]
>>>
>>> columns = [[1,2,3],
               [4],
               [5,6]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*columns))
[(1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4]
c = [5,6]

d = [[x, y, z] for x in a for y in b for z in c]
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a Cartesian product you just need to iterate in all dimensions in this case

For example:

```
for x in dimension_x:
    for y in dimension_y:
         for z in dimension_z:
             use the x,y,z
```

The complexity of the algorithm will always be tough (for 2 arrays -> n2, for 3 -> n3, ..., for M -> n^M where n is the length of the longest array).

Note that you have duplicates:
(a,b) is the same as (b,a). So you can change the algorithm to work faster if you don't need the duplicates.